# Cannot access property of nodes returned from schema procedure call

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I want to view the schema of my graph (Neo4j v4.1.1) that has a large number of labels and relationship types. I am working on a query to specify the labels of interest so that the result is less crowded.

```
CALL db.schema.visualization() YIELD nodes, relationships 
UNWIND nodes AS n 
UNWIND relationships AS r 
RETURN n, r
```

But I can't access any of the properties of the nodes and relationships returned by the procedure call. I have tried:

- `n.labels`
- `n["labels"]`
- `keys(n)`
- `properties(n)`
- `labels(n)`

All of the above return either empty or null values. How can I access these properties so that I can filter the schema results by label?

Comment: Just wondering if you managed to do this eventually?  It seems that the nodes returned by visualization() don't really exist since I wasn't able to query those nodes by id (all of them are negative numbers)

Answer (score 0):

With below query using Keys()  function you can able to see the properties of a selected label. if you want to see multiple labels at a time, you can keep multiple labels in a match query. Neo4j is a no schema database. So, multiple nodes can have same label name with different set of properties. Please let me know if you are looking for something else.

```
MATCH (n:MemberStatus) where n.name="Active" return keys(n)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. My question is specifically about getting the properties of the results returned from `db.schema.visualization` or `db.schema` procedure calls. In my question, I have mentioned the different things I have tried, including `keys()`. I have also mentioned the query I am starting with.

Comment: Yeah, even you can find a query to see the properties of a result, we cannot assure that is the schema for a specific label. Why because, neo4j doesn't have any schema. With the same label we can have different nodes with different set of properties.